# Rails + Postgres - Decimals stored as strings in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table - `boot_camps`. It has a `price` field, which is a decimal(8,2) in the schema. For some reason the values seem to convert to strings. It makes the validation in the model fail:

```
validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
```

With this error:
`ArgumentError: comparison of String with 0 failed`

schema.rb:

```
create_table "boot_camps", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.decimal  "price",             precision: 8, scale: 2
  t.integer  "capacity"
  t.date     "start_date"
  t.date     "end_date"
end
```

If I run `\d boot_camps` in psql I get:

```
                         Table "public.boot_camps"
  Column       |            Type             |                        
Modifiers
-------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------
 id                | integer                     | not null default 
 title             | character varying           |
 price             | numeric(8,2)                |
 capacity          | integer                     |
 start_date        | date                        |
 end_date          | date                        |
```

but a BooCamp record, viewed in the rails console, shows:

```
#<BootCamp:0x007fc3a8e7abd0> {
               :id => 1,
            :title => "test",
            :price => "30.00",
         :capacity => 11,
       :start_date => nil,
         :end_date => nil,
}
```

and

```
BootCamp.last.price.class //=> String < Object
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this article (it explains the reason and how to overcome this in Rails): http://justinmccormick.com/wp/programming/postgres-and-grapeentities-decimals-appear-as-strings

Answer (score 0):

So... found out it was just my oversight actually.

I inherited a codebase that I'm trying to salvage and I just found a method on the model that converts `price` to String. I'll leave this here, in case it happens to anyone else...